# Why I get error for string variable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I have the declared variable:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString* like_id;
```

I call function `GetLike` inside `- (void)viewDidLoad {}`

```
- (void) GetLike {
   if(![self.like_id isEqualToString:@""]){
     // TODO
   }
}
```

I get error: `Thread 1, signal SIGABRT`

Comment: Show how you actually call `GetLike`. Show the relevant portion of the stack trace. BTW - method names should start with lowercase letters.

Comment: @rmaddy You are right, it would be a no-op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString* like_id;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getLike];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)getLike {
    if(![self.like_id isEqualToString:@""]){
        NSLog(@"Liked !");
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Is there any difference @hima

Comment: No, I think there isn't any, Is it working fine or still having that error? You may would like to print whole error description here. @DjamilBahirov

Comment: @hima- how it is be a solution& why there is upvote.